# Restrict Access to one of subdomains, excluding a directory with .htaccess & .htpasswd

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I'm currently have several websites with different subdomains.
They have a common .htaccess file.

Example:

1. sub1.domainname.com
2. sub2.domainname.com
3. sub3.domainname.com
4. exclude.domainname.com
5. sub4.domainname.com
6. ...

And I would like to restrict access to one of them, lets say to **`exclude.domainname.com`**.

The problem is that I also want to allow access to different static files that may be served from **`/files`** folder (ex: `exclude.domainname.com/files/images/image.png`).

I've fininshed with this one solution, but now, when I'm trying to access `exclude.domainname.com` and after entering username and password I'm getting a Server Error message, however static files can be accessed easily without any restrictions.

I will be really appreciate for any help.
Perhaps the probelm with **SetEnvIf** or with general **logic**.

Thank you in advance.

```
    ## Password Protection & Authentification ##

    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Access Protection"
    AuthUserFile "/path/to/the/.htpasswd"
    require valid-user

    # Exclude Environments

    # Set env to deny access
    SetEnvIf Host ^exclude\.domainname\.com$ deny_access
    # Remove env to deny access
    SetEnvIf Request_URI "files/*" !deny_access

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Deny from env=deny_access

    Satisfy any

    ## END Password Protection & Authentification ##
```

PS:

I also tried to set different Environments like allow and deny.

Even try to deny all, then set allow to all hosts except `exclude.domainname.com` like this:

```
SetEnvIf Host ^(?!exclude)\w+\.domainname\.com$ allow_access
```

But without Success.

Comment: Unfortunately not. My solution is almost working: it asks username & password for subdomain and allow access to static files, but it ends up with Server Error after entering username/password for subdomain.

Comment: Sorry this was the link to another answer... https://regex101.com/r/EQKCDv/2

Comment: Sorry, but this is just the same regex as I tried too inside my PS section. I suppose that something wrong with **SetEnvIf** or with the logic in general